# Notice alert trying to get an index of non-array var

Tags: php

I would like to know why PHP doesn't show a 'Notice' alert when I'm trying to get an index of a non-array variable.
This is the code that I used to test:

```
echo ">>> Empty array\n";
$foo = array();
var_dump($foo['var']);

echo "\n>>> Boolean\n";
$foo = false;
var_dump($foo['var']);

echo "\n>>> Null\n";
$foo = null;
var_dump($foo['var']);

echo "\n>>> Int\n";
$foo = 1;
var_dump($foo['var']);
```

Output:

```
>>> Empty array
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: var in /var/www/test.php on line 3
NULL

>>> Boolean
NULL

>>> Null
NULL

>>> Int
NULL
```

Comment: Presumably it is casting array to a string and key to an integer at which point it is a valid PHP operation.

Comment: [String access and modification by character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use *array dereference* (accessing results of an array). As per the implementation of [zend_fetch_dimension_address_read](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ccf863c8ce7e746948fb060d515960492c41ed27/Zend/zend_execute.c#L1249), we can see that this is only implemented for three types: Arrays, Strings and Objects. The default in functionality is that PHP just returns the undefined variable.

If for example you would try the same trick on a String, there is an implementation for array dereferencing for that so you will also get an error:

```
<?php
echo "\n>>> String\n";
$foo = "test";
var_dump($foo['var']);
```

will output:

```
>>> String

Warning:  Illegal string offset 'var' on line 4
```